# What is a formal definition of a line?

Tags: linear-algebra

I am trying to understand what is a line in terms of a linear space. I have checked a few linear algebra books and none has a definition.

Well, I could say it's a one dimensional subspace but then a line described in $\mathbb{R}^2$ with the equation $y = x + 2$ does not go through the origin, so then it's not only a linear subspace.

On the other hand, if I say that a line is anything expressed via a linear equation like $y = b + ax$, then if I consider a finite field, say $\mathbb{F_3}^2$ (i.e. a plane under $GF(3)$), then an equation $y = 1 + 2x$ would describe a figure that have a "jump" when $x$ changes from 1 to 2. E.g. with a basis $(1,0), (0,1)$, the coordinates of such a line are: $(0,1)$, $(1,0)$, $(2,1)$.

Could you help to find the formal definition of a line in a linear space or  point out a textbook where it's properly described? Thanks!

Comment: I should add it's important that I want to find out what's mathematically considered a line in the field of Linear Algebra. In geometries it's defined quite well, mostly because it's one of the key objects there...

Comment: Very often, the reason for difficulty in finding a definition of a mathematical term is that it is not particularly useful. A line essentially conjures a geometrical object in mind and it is useful in that context. Hence in $\mathbb R^n$ we define it as a 1-dimensional subspace.

Comment: Lines are described in Analytic Geometry not in Linear Algebra.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\mathbb{A}^n$ be the [affine space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_space?wprov=sfla1) $\mathbb{R}^n$ over $\mathbb{R}^n$. A **line** is then defined as an affine subspace of $\mathbb{A}^n$ of dimension $1$.
Similarly, a plane will be defined as a subspace of dimension $2$, and an hyperplane as a subspace of dimension $n-1$ (or codimension $1$).

Note that in this way we can define parallelism too: two affine subspace of $\mathbb{A}^n$ are parallel the direction of one contains the direction of the other one.

Your example of line $y=x+2$ is contained in this definition.

This type of definition is part of the so called affine geometry, the part of euclidean geometry dedicated to the study of those properties of euclidean spaces that do not depend on the notion of distance or on the one of angle (more formally, those that do not depend on the inner product of an euclidean vector space).

Comment: Wow, it's a dynamite! Of course, to think about lines we should have a notion of points which appears only the abstraction called Affine Space. Thank you, your answer clears things up to me!

Comment: @mur_tm it might be interesting to note that this definition can be easily extended to a vector space other than $\mathbb{R}^n$. The results are rather interesting: as an example, if we consider a line on the affine space $\mathbb{C}^2$, we obtain that is possible to have two line on a plane which are not parallel and yet do not intersect each other (those lines are called skew lines), which is clearly wrong in $\mathbb{A}^2$.